# converting .htaccess and nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, web, server

Moved the server to nginx. How do I "Transfer" these rules to nginx? I suppose I need the number of nginx configs?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 404 /.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)|dump.sql(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (dfiles/.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dfiles.php?request=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(jscss/.*)!(img/.*)!(image.php.*)!(video.php.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rad_pr=1&request=$1
```

I'm try use nginx converter, but it's not working.

Comment: nginx offers a documentation that explains the configuration option it offers. I would suggest that you use that, try to implement your solution. _Then_ , if you fail to get that to work correctly as you expect or require, _then_ is the time to come here and ask. Posting your current implementation and a precise description of what is not working as expected and what happens instead.

Comment: Please understand that SO is not a free coding service. We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to _help_ you doing your work. But that means that you need to start doing your work yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly I need to read in the nginx documentation to start understanding how to write rules in it. I would be grateful if someone sent me such material. Unfortunately, I have a limited time to delve into the full workings of nginx.

Comment: First hit on google: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/